# creating array of objects

Tags: java, arrays

I try to create an array with the object stock, I wrote this code to create a stock object s and add it to the a array.

```
private stock s = new stock("name", "price", 22); 
stock[] d =new stock[2];
d[0]= s;
d[1]= s;
```

I get these errors :

```
']' expected
d[0]= s;

illegal start of type
d[0]= s;
```

Comment: Where is this code? In a class? In a method? Outside it?

Comment: @Nivas From the `private` modifier, 500 rep says in the class body.

Comment: @chrylis I think so too, outside a method. Just wanted to be sure.

Comment: please follow the standard convention of use upper case letters to start class names.  This will avoid confusion, both for you and those who are reading your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're outside a method, you'll need an initializer block (or to use a constructor) -

```
private stock s = new stock("name", "price", 22);
private stock[] d = new stock[2];
{
    d[0] = s;
    d[1] = s;
}
```

If you're inside a method, you can do it like so -

```
stock s = new stock("name", "price", 22);
stock[] d = new stock[2];
d[0] = s;
d[1] = s;
// stock[] d = new stock[] { s, s }; // <-- or like this
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a reference to an array slot isn't an initialization, and you can't do that inside the class body. Put that initialization in a constructor instead.

(And use capital letters for class names in Java; it's a universal convention that you should follow.)